# Angularjs select "fake" model updating

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form with dropdown:

```
<select class="form-control input-sm" 
    ng-disabled="!editMode" 
    ng-model="case.LawyerParticipation.LawyerID" 
    ng-options="lawyer.ID as lawyer.Name for lawyer in lawyers" 
    ng-change="changed()"></select>
```

Default LawyerID value is "null".
When fired change event then "changed" function show me the value of "case.LawyerParticipation.LawyerID":

```
$scope.changed = function () {
     alert($scope.case.LawyerParticipation.LawyerID);
};
```

And It show that model changed as I expected. $scope.case.LawyerParticipation.LawyerID changes to value that I select in dropdown.
Next step I want to send this value on the server. I click submit button and function "updateCase" fired:

```
$scope.updateCase = function () {
    alert($scope.case.LawyerParticipation.LawyerID);

    $http.post("/case/update", $scope.case ).success(function (updatedCase) {
        $scope.case  = updatedCase;
    });
};
```

Alert in this function show me that all right and "LawyerID" has new value.
Then "post" happens and in console I see that the model posted on server has LawyerID = "null", it comes also null on server! What I doing wrong? Why it's null?

Answer (score 0):

There might be some typo in your server code, add your server code to the question.

```
$scope.updateCase = function () {
    alert($scope.case.LawyerParticipation.LawyerID);

    $http.post("/case/update", {data:$scope.case} ).success(function (updatedCase) {
        $scope.case  = updatedCase;
    });
};
```